# Google Spreadsheet Counta Two string conditions in separate rows

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

I am trying to achieve a counta of two string conditions.

There is a database with:
Columns C2:C which contains a string of languages.
Columns F2:F which contains a string of TRUE / FALSE.

```
   C         F
German     TRUE
German     TRUE
German     FALSE
German     FALSE
French     FALSE
French     TRUE
French     TRUE
```

etc.

The answer I'm looking for: (IF DASHBOARD!B12 = "German", AND F:F = "TRUE" , then the answer would be 2)

I have already tried:

```
=COUNTA(IF(AND(C:C=DASHBOARD!B12,F:F="TRUE"),1,0))
//This gives me the answer of 1?

=COUNTA(IFERROR( FILTER( F2:F , SEARCH( "TRUE" , F2:F ) ) ) )
// This gives me the correct answer of 89

=COUNTA(IFERROR( FILTER( C2:C , SEARCH( DASHBOARD!B12 , C2:C ) ) ) )
//This gives me the correct answer of 37
```

How do you merge the last two expressions so that the counta will ONLY count those where column F = TRUE and column C = DASHBOARD!B12?

I have already tried =SUMPRODUCT() and =ARRAYFORMULA() to no avail, there must be something that is going wrong with such a simple expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use true() and false() function instead of string "true", "false". It is better to put in function if().
You can use more condition in filter(),like: filter(C:F,C:C="French",C:C="TRUE")

I have made a example sheetsheet for your reference.
Please check below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhDkbjKh37REdGloc2NFbDlXeGNrSm1TTHhyVFFWelE

I believe the data in C:D is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! In addition to the example which you supplied, here is what I have added to the DATADUMP - `=iferror(filter(AGENTS!C:F,AGENTS!C:C=DASHBOARD!B12,AGENTS!F:F=DASHBOARD!C12))` It seems to need a few more seconds than usual to read the counta in the DATADUMP column, but it's all working fine!